# Unity 2D Sprite Cutout with border

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites

I'm working on a 2D simulation game and have one object floating on top of another one. I have a Sprite Mask on the object on top to achieve cutout like effect so the background is visible where the Sprite Mask is. It looks like this:

[image: Cutout overlay]

I want to add a border around that cutout, that would automatically blend with the border of the bottom object when it reaches the sides. Similar like a Subtract mode in Sketch (or other vector-based graphics editor):

[image]

How can I achieve this? The desired outcome would look like this:

[image]

Thank you!